# black Rounded edge in recyclerview

Tags: android, imageview, android-custom-view, cornerradius

i'm trying to set cornerRadiuse to image view like code below

but sometime  in RecyclerView edges go to black

in one of the pages i have to resize an cornerRadus image

i tried to use bitmap instead of this class but it have terrible performance in recyclerview

[image: a busy cat]

```
class CImageView : AppCompatImageView {

private var mMaskPath: Path = Path()
private val mMaskPaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
var mCornerRadius = 0f
constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : super(context, attributeSet) {
    init(attributeSet)
}
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {
    init( attrs)
}
private fun init(set: AttributeSet?) {
    if(isInEditMode) {
        return
    }
    if (set == null) {
        return
    }
    ViewCompat.setLayerType(this, View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
    mMaskPaint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
    mMaskPaint.color = resources.getColor(R.color.accent_material_dark)

    val ta = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(set, R.styleable.CImageView)
    mCornerRadius = ta.getDimension(R.styleable.CImageView_cornerRadiuses, 0f)
    ta.recycle()
    invalidate()
}
override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldW: Int, oldH: Int) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldW, oldH)

    if (w != oldW || h != oldH) {
        generateMaskPath(w, h)
        try {
            val s = w.toFloat() / oldW * mCornerRadius
            if (s < 100)
                mCornerRadius = s
        } catch (e: Exception) {
        }
    }
    invalidate()
}

private fun generateMaskPath(w: Int, h: Int) {
    try{
    mMaskPath = Path()
    mMaskPath.addRoundRect(RectF(0f, 0f, w.toFloat(), h.toFloat()), mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW)
    mMaskPath.fillType = Path.FillType.INVERSE_WINDING
    }catch (e:Exception){
        //whene h = 0 => image not load on screen
    }
}
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    if(isInEditMode){
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        return
    }
    if (canvas.isOpaque) {
        canvas.saveLayerAlpha(0f, 0f, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat(), 255, 0)
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    canvas.drawPath(mMaskPath, mMaskPaint)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after search a lot i found a library fix this issue 

https://github.com/dipkastel/RoundedImageView

its so simple and very useful

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Glide to load the image and add a [rounded corners transformation](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/transformations.html).

```
Glide.with(imgView)
.load("http://my_image.jpeg")
.apply(RequestOptions().transform(RoundedCorners(12))) // This is the corner radius in pixels
.into(imgView)
```

Comment: hi, welcome to StackOverflow, can you include some code snippets or examples also into the answer as just giving a link is too risky, the page might not be available later :)